# Accessing another database in MySQL from Android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, multiple-databases

I am using XAMPP with PHP and PHPMyAdmin as interface and trying to query information from one database, onlineportal, and inserting into another database, androidchatterdatabase, within one action. Given the code below it is not allowing to query information from `$dbOnlinePortal` as if I change the query statements from `$dbOnlinePortal->query()` to `$db->query()`, it shows results but returns '0' when selecting from onlineportal.types and onlineportal.campaigns.

Can I start another instance of `new MySQL` in the PHP index file, therefore giving a connection to two databases simultaneously? Or is there a better way to access multiple databases on one server than what I am doing?

```
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "androidchatterdatabase";
$dbName2 = "onlineportal";

$db = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
$dbOnlinePortal = new MySQL($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName2);


case "clickSpecial":
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password))
        {
            if (isset($_REQUEST['specialId']))
            {   
                // Get data
                $specialId = $_REQUEST['specialId'];    
                $timePeriod = $_REQUEST['timePeriod'];
                $cityLocationId = $_REQUEST['cityLocationId'];

                // Get the restaruant id, which will then serve to get the 
                // selected restaurant categories
                $sqlRestaurantCategorization = 
                       "SELECT distinct category_id 
                        FROM onlineportal.types
                        WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM onlineportal.campaigns WHERE id = '".$specialId."');";

                // Get the categeories of the restraurant       
                if($getRestaurantCategorization = $dbOnlinePortal->query($sqlRestaurantCategorization))
                {   
                    // Insert those into the table
                    while($rowRestaurantCategorization = $dbOnlinePortal-> fetchObject($getRestaurantCategorization))
                    {
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `users_click` (`usersId`, `restaurantCategoryId`, `timePeriod`, `cityLocationId`, `clickedDt`)
                                              VALUES('".$userId."','".$rowRestaurantCategorization->restaurantCategoryId."','".$timePeriod."','".$cityLocationId."',NOW());";                   

                        error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                        if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                        {
                                $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                        }               
                        else 
                        {
                                $out = FAILED;
                        }                   

                    }   

                }
                else
                {
                    $out = FAILED;
                }       

            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }   

        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   

    break;
```

Comment: So you are saying the result of `$dbOnlinePortal->query($sqlRestaurantCategorization)` is `0`? Having two `new MySQL` the way you isn't a problem.

Comment: Yes, when using $db the result of pulling from online.types then inserts into user_clicks as "0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax to insert into another DB using an insert stmt is this:

```
USE `old_database`;
INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)
SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column7`, `old_table`.`column5` 
FROM `old_table`
```

**Edit:**

Did you try doing it like this:

```
INSERT INTO `users_click` (`usersId`, `restaurantCategoryId`, `timePeriod`, `cityLocationId`, `clickedDt`)
                   VALUES ('".$userId."','(SELECT distinct category_id 
                                           FROM onlineportal.types
                                           WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM onlineportal.campaigns WHERE id = '".$specialId."'))','".$cityLocationId."',NOW());";
```

Comment: No, as the code I posted I need to select from one database and use that result as part of an insert into another database. How can I access another database from the case server call?

Comment: I guess I'd have to see some data to finish this out

Comment: I solved the problem, I was pulling the wrong column from the previous query, as the insert was: `.$rowRestaurantCategorization->restaurantCategoryId.`, when it should have been `.$rowRestaurantCategorization->category_id.`. You are free to upload that solution if you want...

Comment: Check my comment right above yours, I solved my own problem, you can write it up if you wish

Answer (score 0):

Just a detail: if you're using WAMP or MAMP, meaning a local server, opening 2 or more databases will work. But, in production mode, you'll have to check if it's possible or not, as it will depend on your web site provider. 
In many cases, when you have two different accounts, each one with a DB, for security reason you would be unable to open the second DB (second account) from a script on first account. And if the two database are on two complelty different web serve, this would be certainly not possible.

So, perform a small test before coding, in order to avoid discovering the problem later.

If you can't access one DB from another account, the only safe way would be to put a script on account 2, that you'll call from a script in account 1. Receiving the "order" from script 1, script 2 will query DB-2, prepare the answer, send it back to script 1 which will decode it and use it on it's DB1 query.

Comment: I am planning on keeping everything on the same account even in production mode. However, I will have multiple databases but I am in no way going to have multiple accounts as the data needs to be separated but still accessible from both the android app and the Rails App.